# Referring two file systems in a single site

Tags: 7, files

I have production and staging environment that use the same file system (Amazon S3). I need to change the user profile picture saving path of my staging environment to local file system and other files to be saved in S3.

Is that possible?

Comment: Why bother? S3 has unlimited space.

Comment: yes we can, i have cloned the production environment to staging with different database. Hence any changes related to profile picture in staging will affect production right?

Comment: simply wrong, you push from staging to production code & configuration changes only. The image reference is saved in the database and is not part of the configuration system.

Comment: if am not wrong, only the path will be saved in database, whereas file will be saved in the file system under **pictures** folder.

Comment: yeah... and? what's your point here? all that matter is the path that's saved in the DB at the end of the day. As long as this path remains the same, nothing will change.

Comment: @NoSssweat are you saying it’s good practice to put in your production environment testing/staging data? If not, that seems like a good reason not to do it.

Comment: @PrasanthR how do you have configured the S3 integration? A solution might be creating a separate area for staging and simply updating the endpoint. Another option is disabling this and using for staging a local file system. You could always use stage_file_proxy or a proxy to reference production images which aren’t at the other environment.

Comment: @rovr138 How many profile pics is he going to be uploading in the test area? I like to [KISS](https://www.google.ca/search?q=kiss+principle) it.

Comment: @NoSssweat Maybe and with S3 it might be okay. But they might also be using devel to generate test content there and that can quickly add up after multiple sessions.

Comment: @rovr138 fair point, but OPer never answered my `Why bother?` question. Maybe if there is a ton of images might be worth doing something about it. Another simple solution would be to clone the S3 bucket and use that newly cloned bucket for the staging site.

Comment: @NoSssweat I agree. OP definitely could provide more info on the reason why. If there’s not a ton of content, reusing the same environment could work. Cloning it down is another solution if space permits and cloning the S3 bucket is another option. But I agree, they could better explain why or what they’re trying to solve.

Comment: @NoSssweat, rovr138 thanks for your reply, hence i have created folder inside production root and updated it as root folder for my staging enviroment & issue resolved.